# How to get TimeInMillis for different TimeZone

Tags: java, date, timezone, epoch

I'm tired of searching about so simple question.
**Please don't suggest me using Joda Time or Java 8**, I want to use the simple *java.time.** and I have Java 7.

I just want to get the *currentTimeInMillis* for some specific time zone, all examples I found just providing me a solution how to print the actual date by using

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Some/Location"));
```

But I don't want the date, I just want the **actual timestamp**.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns milliseconds since January 1 1970 00:00 UTC.  Are you asking for milliseconds since January 1 1970 00:00 in a different timezone?  How is that useful?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is a server that running in my TimeZone, but other users are located in different TimeZone, and I need to compare their action's time if it's later than my or not

Comment: You will find comparison of dates much easier if you keep them all in UTC.  You can *present them to the user* in different timezones, of course, but internally it’s a good idea to use UTC as much as possible.

Comment: It's good idea, but i can't do that, the time from my TimeZone is actually saved by Jenkins under tag <timestamp> for triggered build, so i have no control on that

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what input data you are working with?  What value is in that timestamp?  What exactly is the value to which you are comparing it?

Comment: Jenkins saved time zone: <timestamp>1601479989846</timestamp>, and code that running on the other user's PC should take current time in millis, and compare to Jenkins value, but i can't just compare because it will get value corresponding to the other TimeZone, not to Jenkin's TimeZone

Comment: I agree with what I think you meant to say: for getting the milliseconds since the epoch, using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, through [the backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) would be overkill. If you wanted to do any other work with date or time, not suggesting exactly that would mean not giving you the best suggestion. If not for you I would at least suggest java.time for anyone else reading along now or in the future. It’s the best there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter which part of the world you are in, `System.currentTimeMillis()` will always return you no. of milliseconds from `midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC` i.e. if you execute the following code at the same time on the JVMs located in London, New Delhi and New York, the result will be the same because `System.currentTimeMillis()` is independent of time-zone.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Thus, if your application and the application running in another time-zone, both are capturing the timestamp as the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` you can safely compare their values without worrying about the differences in the time-zone.